# change URL parameter MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC application with the following URL format.

> http://localhost:25825/en/applications

where

- http://localhost:25825/ = base URL
- en = language
- applications = rest of URL

Currently I have the following to change the language.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="~/en">@Resources.Global.LanguagesEnglish</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/tr">@Resources.Global.LanguagesTurkish</a></li>
</ul>
```

but doing so clears the rest of URL part and goes to home page. Is there any way to change the language while preserving the remaining part of URL?

There is also translation for routes

```
.ForController<ApplicationController>()
.ForAction(x => x.Index())
.AddTranslation("uygulamalar")
```

so

> http://localhost:25825/en/applications

becomes

> http://localhost:25825/tr/uygulamalar

Comment: you can set default route language prefix after that you set you router URL `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { lang ="en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }`

Comment: And also you can do `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) { routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "en/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } ); }` or you go with also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would make perfect sense! Your href is the base of your app, and you aren't doing anything to grab the current page or append a specific page.

A simple JS way would be a function to get the correct path based on some attribute (maybe even a data-attribute):

```js
function getLang(lang){
  // this would be your URL and not just a console log
  console.log("~/" + lang + window.location.pathname);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="getLang('en')">@Resources.Global.LanguagesEnglish</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="getLang('tr')">@Resources.Global.LanguagesTurkish</a></li>
</ul>
```

You also mentioned MVC, so perhaps building the URLs on the server makes the most sense:

```
<ul>
   @foreach(var resource in @Resources.Global.Where(x => x.Contains("Languages")).ToList())
{
      <li><a href='@($"~/{resource}/applications")'>@resource</a></li>
}    
</ul>
```